# Converting a base10 number to another base using % and / operands

Tags: java

My professor assigned us to create a program for converting a base 10 number to another base. He gave us these instructions:

First compute place0 -- the units place. Remember this comes from the first division so it is the remainder when the base 10 number is divided by the base (HINT %). Then compute the quotient (integer division / will do it!). You can either store the result back in base10Num or declare a new variable for the quotient. Now compute place1 -- this is the remainder when the quotient from the preceding step is divided by the base. Then compute the new quotient. Repeat the idea from above to compute place2 and the next quotient. Repeat again to compute place3

My current code is:

```
package baseconversion;
import java.util.*;
public class BaseConversion
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {

 int base;       // the new base

 int base10Num;   // the number in base 10

 int maxNumber;   // the maximum number that will fit

                   // in 4 digits in the new base

 int place0;     // digit in the 1's (base^0) place

 int place1;     // digit in the base^1 place

 int place2;     // digit in the base^2 place

 int place3;     // digit in the base^3 place

 int quotient0;

 int quotient1;

 int quotient2;

 String baseBNum = new String (""); // the number in the new base

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println();

 System.out.println ("Base Conversion Program");

 System.out.println();

 System.out.print ("Please enter a base (2 - 9): ");

 base = scan.nextInt();

 System.out.print ("Please enter a base 10 number to convert: ");

 base10Num = scan.nextInt();

 place0 = base10Num%base;

 quotient0 = base10Num/base;

 place1 = quotient0%base;

 quotient1 = place1/base;

 place2 = quotient1%base;

 quotient2 = place2/base;

 place3 = quotient2%base ;

 baseBNum = Integer.toString(place0) + Integer.toString(place1) + Integer.toString(place2) + Integer.toString(place3);

 System.out.println(baseBNum);   

  }

 }
```

When base10Num = 13 and base = 2, my professor says baseBNum should equal 1101. Despite this, I keep getting 1000 as my baseBNum value. Following my professor's instructions, what should I do to fix my code?

Comment: i might be crazy but your code looks right to me, are you sure this is the output you are getting? did you try debugging your code step by step and see if all variable have the right value?

Comment: I think you're perfectly sane my guy. I tried it again, and I still get 1000 as my output. I checked, and all variables should be getting the right value. The code might be right, this wouldn't be the first time my professor goofed.